# How to enable separate compilation of CUDA with ROS?

Tags: cuda, ros

In default, CUDA requires that all device codes are compiled in a single translation/compilation unit unless you allow the separate compilation/linking of the device code.

But how can I enable it in a CMakeList.txt for the ROS (or more generally camke)?

The following is my current CMakeList file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(edt)
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

# Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp
    rospy
    std_msgs
    )

FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=sm_61;-g;-G" CACHE STRING "nvcc flags" FORCE)
SET (CUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD ON CACHE BOOL "nvcc verbose" FORCE)


catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
    )

include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${ZED_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

cuda_add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
    src/main.cpp
    src/test.cu
    src/test2.cu
    )

add_dependencies(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
    ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
    )

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${ZED_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

The ***test2.cu defines a function that is called in test.cu*** (see **cuda_add_executable** in the CMakeList), and it currently gives error said the .o file cannot be created.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME}PROPERTY CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

That's the common way, in my understanding.